# Regex to match a word NOT within a specific number of words of another word

Tags: regex

Hope I can explain this one.

I've got a regex for matching two words near each other.  For example, if I want to find the word "account" and "number" within 5 words of each other:

\baccount\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,6}?number\b

This works perfectly.

Now I need to find a way to search for a word as long as it is NOT within 2 words of another word.

For example, I need a regex that matches "Butthead"  but only if  "Beavis" is not within 2 words, either BEFORE OR AFTER Butthead.

So  Butthead and Beavis would not match.  Beavis and Butthead would not match.  But Beavis Sure Is a Giant Butthead would match because Beavis and Butthead are NOT within 2 words.

Comment: I dont think thats possible with just regex. What language are you using the run this?

Comment: What do you want to happen with "Beavis sure is a giant butthead. Beavis"? (i.e the word occurs both near and not-near the other word)

Comment: Here is again an example of where people want to write a regex when there is a simpler way, given that you're doing this in a programming language (as opposed to some tool that only takes regexes). Why not just match every occurence of these words, then, for each match (in a loop) create a simple check if the other word is too close to the other, and ignore it if it is. (That's not saying that regex exercises like these can't be a bit interesting.)

Comment: @steinar, if you look at comments to Paul's answer, it looks like this  *is* for "some tool that only takes regexes".

Comment: Since you mentioned below that this is in email rules, it really feels like you are overreaching what the system is capable of.  There may be better alternatives - what actual problem are you trying to solve?  I can't imagine email where this rule is meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if your regexp system supports variable length negative look behinds.
I do not think many regex engines support this yet. I know that perl and php do not yet support this. I was not able to test since I use perl and php for my regex testing.

/(?<!beavis(?:\s+\w+)?\s+)butthead(?!(?:\s+\w+)?beavis)/

Comment: Without a negative look behind I cannot see an alternative way too match this properly.  The proposal submitted by Flo works except for the case where butthead occurs on a line by itself with no beavis present.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do two matches? Match to find the occurence of the word anywhere (easy) then discard that match if the word is not near the other word (you already have a solution for that).

Comment: I don't think I can, because I'm doing this within a "Rules Engine" of an e-mail filtering system which filters emails based on certain criteria, so I need a single regex to define the critera.

Comment: If the word occurs both near and not-near the other word, I want it to not match, because it does occur near and that's the important thing.

Answer (score 0):

((?!((\Butthead\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,2}?Beavis\b)|(\Beavis\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,2}?Butthead\b))).)*

maybe something like this... didn't try it though...
basically i've tryed your way using the following logic:
NOT( (contains Butthead 2 words Beavis) OR (contains Beavis 2 words Butthead) )