# Skipping specific number of words in a string using Regex

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, string-search

I have a string

> "pqr hello world merger was to be undertaken between xyz as the sole acquirer but got
> delayed"

I want to make sure that

> "delayed"

always comes after 5 words or more following

> "merger"

.

How can this be achieved using regex and C#?

---

#### Solved

Got the answer after reading this: [http://www.princeton.edu/~mlovett/reference/Regular-Expressions.pdf](http://www.princeton.edu/%7Emlovett/reference/Regular-Expressions.pdf)

Solution:

```
Regex.IsMatch(articlecontent.ToLower().Trim(), @"\bmerger\W+(?:\w+\W+){5," + count_of_words_in_article + @"}?\bdelayed", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

The idea is to find "merger" NEAR "delayed" at any distance after 5 words.

Comment: exactly 5 words or more that 5 words

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to match a word NOT within a specific number of words of another word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025233/regex-to-match-a-word-not-within-a-specific-number-of-words-of-another-word)

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookbehind

```
(?<=merger(\s+\w+){5}\s+)delayed
```

Answer (score 1):

## Forward

The problem I have with this type of question:

- What happens if you have "pqr hello world **merger** was **merger** to be undertaken between **merger** xyz as the sole acquirer but got **delayed**". Each instance of `merger` is followed by at least one `delayed` which is more than 4 words away, however each merger doesn't have it's own delayed.

It would be easier to find test for the bad things then use program logic to except or reject the result.

## Description

This regex will match all of the strings which violate your conditions. If the regex doesn't match, then the string should be considered good.

- is there a `merger` which has a trailing `merger`
- does each `merger` have a corresponding instance of `delayed`
- does the `delayed` appear with the first 4 words after each `merger`

In addition to looking for the bad things the expression should do the following:

- handle multiple line strings correctly
- ensure `merger` and `delayed` are not part of a larger word

`(?:^|\s)merger(?:(?=([\s\r\n]+(?:(?!delayed\b)\w+[\r\n\s]+)*?(?:merger|$)(?:[\s\r\n]|$)))|(?=([\s\r\n]+(?:\w+[\r\n\s]+){0,4}delayed(?:[\s\r\n]|$))))`

[image]

## Example

**Sample Text**

Note the line break

```
pqr hello world merger was merger to be 
delayed undertaken between merger xyz as the sole acquirer but got delayed
```

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
          Regex re = new Regex(@"(?:^|\s)merger(?:(?=([\s\r\n]+(?:(?!delayed\b)\w+[\r\n\s]+)*?(?:merger|$)(?:[\s\r\n]|$)))|(?=([\s\r\n]+(?:\w+[\r\n\s]+){0,4}delayed(?:[\s\r\n]|$))))",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
          MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
          int mIdx=0;
          foreach (Match m in mc)
           {
            for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
              }
            mIdx++;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

**Matches**

Note these are the bad instances which breaks your defined rules. If there where no matches then it would be a good string. If capture group 1 is populated then the did not have a corresponding `delayed`. If capture group 2 is populated then `merger` had a `delayed` within the first 4 words.

```
[0][0] =  merger
[0][1] =  was merger 
[0][2] = 

[1][0] =  merger
[1][1] = 
[1][2] =  to be 
delayed
```

Comment: Regex.IsMatch(articlecontent.ToLower().Trim(), @"\bmerger\W+(?:\w+\W+){5," + count_of_words_in_article + @"}?\bdelayed", RegexOptions.Multiline

Comment: Technically that finds the word delayed when it is near the word merger, however that wasn't your original question. Which said you needed to insure the word delayed appeared 5 or more words away from merger.

Comment: I guess 5 or more words away would be same as NEAR if it yields the same result.I guess it works for me in that way. Sorry, if my explanation to the question was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
/merger\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+delayed/
```